# AddEventListener pass event arg in to function

Tags: javascript, events

So i have aproblem, i relly like the way of doing event listeners this way

```
cont1.addEventListener("click", function()
    {

        cont2.style.backgroundColor = "grey";

    }, false);
```

this all works fine np with that. but when i try to pass Event arg in to function like that:

```
cont1.addEventListener("click", function(e)
    {

        cont2.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        e.target.innerHTML +="1";

    }, false);
```

i wont get any event arg at all. how can i solve it while still using annon function there ?

Comment: How can you say that you are not getting event argument there?

Comment: Have you checked the browser's dev console for errors? What does "not getting any event arg" actually mean? If you add `console.log(e)` as the first line of the function what is logged? (Note: whether your function is anonymous is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 2):

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sapu61oj/)**

```
e.target.style.innerHTML
```

should be

```
e.target.innerHTML
```

`innerHTML` is not a style

```
e.target.innerHTML +="1";
```

note: if it is a `input` field then you need to use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: it is my bad, but i am still not getting that Event arg for some reason.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev what is cont1? is it a input field or what?

Comment: @AntonStafeyev it's working see https://jsfiddle.net/sapu61oj/ .can you show fiddle example?